# Refresh a Table in Access VBA in background?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, refresh

I want to refresh the Table in Access automatically every time after the Command Button is clicked. My code below works fine, but it will switch/open the Table. I would like to make it stay in the Form window only, not switch to the Table.
Any idea is appreciated:

```
    Private Sub Command0_Click()
    ''MsgBox Time
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb

    currID = Time
    n = "lala"

    db.Execute "INSERT INTO Table1 ([Task],[From],[To]) VALUES ('" & n & "',#" & currID & "#,#" & currID & "#)", dbFailOnError
    Set db = Nothing

    DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, "Table1"
    DoCmd.Requery
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataTable, "Table1", acLast

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your form is also bound to `Table1`.

So instead of

```
DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, "Table1"
DoCmd.Requery
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataTable, "Table1", acLast
```

you can use

```
Me.Requery
Me.Recordset.MoveLast
```

Comment: That would work if the table is behind the current form. What if you need to refresh the table that is the source for a sub-sub-form which is not active?

Comment: As long as you have a handle to the form and the name of the contained subform control(s) you also can reference the recordset(s) of the form(s) in the subform control(s) and refresh them in the same way. Sample: `Me.SubFormControlName.Form.Requery` , `Me.SubFormControlName.Form.Recordset.MoveLast` and so on: `Me.SubFormControlName.Form.SubSubFormControlName.Form.Requery` . Maybe you would have to use this syntax to reference a control in the subform control: `Me.SubFormControlName.Form.Controls("SubSubFormControlName").Form.Requery`. Can't prove that right now.

Answer (score 0):

Me.Requery

Me.Recordset.MoveFirst

worked for me as well and positioned the active record as I would generally prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Me.Recordset.Requery` this command does requery and keeps current record.